# OnNavigatedFrom is not called when the app is suspended

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Today I've encountered strange problem - seems that on my device (v. 8.10.14203.306) *OnNavigatedFrom* event is not getting called when the app is being suspended. As far as I remember some time ago it was working ok, and exacly [as documentation stays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx):

> Note  On Windows Phone, OnNavigatedFrom() is called when the app is suspended. OnNavigatedTo() is not called when the app is resumed.

I've tried a simple example ([available at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/OnNavigatedFromProblem)):

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    Debug.WriteLine("Navigation");
    this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

when there is normal navigation (e.g. by back button) the event is fired, but no more when the app is suspended - both in debug and release mode. I've also checked if the *Suspending* event is fired and it turnes out that it is:

```cs
// uncomment this to check if app is being suspended
App.Current.Suspending += (sender, e) => this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is to make sure that you're calling [Frame.GetNavigationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate.aspx) from within your Application.Suspending handler (this is usually done by SuspensionManager.SaveAsync). According to the docs:

> Calling this method will call **Page.OnNavigatedFrom** for the current page using **NavigationMode.Forward**. **GetNavigationState** is usually called when the application is being suspended, so the current page is navigated away from.

Comment: That's correct. I thought that *OnNavigatedFrom* is called automatically, not by *SuspensionManager* (in this case). So it's seems that it's possible that there is an app that when it's suspended *OnNavigatedFrom* won't be called - nice to know. Thank you.